# Passing Activity Instance to IntentService

Tags: java, android

Im am trying to pass an instance of my activity to an intent service. The reason for this is the intent service does a lot of background server communication and if there is an network error or the server returns an error I want to display a pop up message.

When i create the service i use this

```
    Intent service = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
    Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
    b2.putParcelable(StringsConfig.OBJECT_DELIVERABLES, objects);
    service.putExtras(b2);
    startService(service);
```

Is there a way to pass an instance of an Activity over to it. I also have a method inside the SyncService class that accept an Activity but i dont know how to create an instance of the sync service class, pass the activity over via the method, and then start the sync service.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a great idea to pass an Activity instance to an Intent Service. If your long running Background Service needs to show a dialog message, you are much better off modelling it as an Intent.

Just do:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourDialogActivity.class);
dialogIntent.putStringExtra(Constants.TITLE, "Your Dialog Title");
dialogIntent.putIntExtra(Constants.MESSAGE, R.string.yourErrorMessageId);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

That way, the service contract is a lot cleaner.

Comment: So you recommend launching a dialog intent from the background service? Can you do that?

Comment: You're proposing to make a new activity just to show a dialog? I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: It does not have to be a different activity. It can be the same activity that intercepts the event (add a new Intent action). You can re-use an existing activity by sending a broadcast.

Comment: maybe, but it wasn't specified in your answer. also when you do this approach, if the activity is already in the background, it will launch it (which may not be what you want) and instead of going through onNewIntent as I think you'd like to happen, it would go through the normal activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way for an IntentService to communicate to an activity is via BroadcastReceiver. Take a look at this example:

In the activity that you want your IntentService to communicate with, create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for a specific intent action (a String). Here my example is called batchProcessReceiver, and listens for the BATCH_PROCESS_RECEIVER action. BATCH_PROCESS_RECEIVER can be a public static constant in your Activity.

```
private BroadcastReceiver batchProcessReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BATCH_PROCESS_RECEIVER)) {
            // do what you need to do here
        }
    }
};
```

In your activity's onResume:

```
registerReceiver(batchProcessReceiver, new IntentFilter(BATCH_PROCESS_RECEIVER));
```

onPause:

```
unregisterReceiver(batchProcessReceiver);
```

Then at a point in your IntentService, you can do

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(MyActivity.BATCH_PROCESS_RECEIVER));
```

to trigger the action you want to do in your activity.